# Access the last document relationing it with an user

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my app users send a form to the server, I'm retrieving the last one sent in the next way:

```
const property = set[set?.length -1 ]
```

But I would like to retrieve not the last form sent in general but the last one sent by the user using the app. I was trying with:

```
if (user._id === set?.owner)
```

But if the userID isn't the same that the one who sent the last form it won't return anything and without the condition it just show the last form sent independently of the user accesing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the array to find possible valid matches first.

```
const setByUser = set.filter(form => form.owner === user._id);
```

Then get whichever one you want from that array.